# WPF listview header hover/pressed color

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, hover, styles

I'm trying to style the header of a listview depending on hover/pressed/etc. events.

So far I tried a few things such as a trigger like the following but this does not work on my machine (a Vista Ultimate x64)

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And the listview code:

```
     <ListView VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1}" >
                <GridViewColumn Header="abc"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="cde"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.DataContext>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListViewItem Content="zxc"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.DataContext>
    </ListView>
```

The behaviour I expect is for the background of the header that I hover to become green.

Any ideas?

NT

Comment: In a new project I put your ListView into the Grid and the Style into the Window.Resources and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have reported this as a bug on Connect:

https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=475669

Answer (score 1):

This is confirmed as a bug, and will not be fixed in time for .NET framework 4.0 as per the MS drone's response in Microsoft Connect.

Hooray for closed source software yet again...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does.

If it were open-source, then I would've drilled down, fixed it and provided a patch myself.
Then me and others who would use the "development" version would benefit in the mean time.
Now we don't even know when it's getting fixed, if ever. There are so many bugs that have not been fixed for years in .NET and other closed source projects.

Closed source does not allow you to do this. And this is another reason why I will strive to use open source.

Regards
NT

Answer (score 0):

Just take the provided Control Template Microsoft provides and adjust it how you see fit.  That's how we remove all the additional highlighting Microsoft adds per control.

You can find the templates at this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773(v=VS.100).aspx